# Can I interchange the limit without getting a different answer?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

I have a conceptual question.

Suppose I am given a function to integrate over a unit sphere $\mathbb S^2,$ i.e., $$\iiint_{\mathbb S^2} f(x,y,z) \, dV.$$

When I transfer it to spherical coordinates, I know that I can follow some convention like $x = r \cos a$, $y=r\sin a \cos b$ and $z=r\sin a \sin b.$ (I use these variables.)

Now my question is this: do I get the same answer if I use the limits

1. $0 \leq r \leq 1,$ $0 \leq a \leq \pi,$ and $0 \leq b \leq 2 \pi$ and
2. $0 \leq r \leq 1,$ $0 \leq a \leq 2 \pi,$ and $0 \leq b \leq \pi?$

I think I will get the same answers, but still, the picture is relatively hard to draw here, so I can't include it, but I will be highly obliged if you can confirm or answer this.

Comment: This really is a Fubini type question. By my knowledge, if the region is finite, then the order of integration can be exchanged.

Comment: Then what about the answer below. I actually got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Observe that the region described by the first equation is the unit sphere $\mathbb S^2;$ however, the region described by the second equation is certainly not the unit sphere. One can check this by computing the volume of the two objects: we have that $\iiint_{\mathbb S^2} 1 \, dV = \frac{4 \pi}{3};$ however, we have that $$\iiint_\mathcal R 1 \, dV = \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 r^2 \sin a \, dr \, da \, db = 0.$$

Comment: Here, I am using $\mathcal R$ to denote the region described (in spherical coordinates) by the inequalities in (2.)

Comment: Can you also give the picture of the second region? Like what is that then?

Comment: I don't know if that is actually possible. By your convention, $a$ is the angle of declination from the $z$-axis, so for $a > \pi,$ things get weird.